# How to create smart contracts and tokens without using any cryptocurency?

Tags: tokens

I am new to Blockchain and I have read to create tokens smart contracts are required and to create a smart contract,ether is required. I wanted to know is there anyway I can create tokens without using ether.

Comment: You can create whatever you want, but in order to deploy it, you'll need some ether.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy and to interact with a smart contract on the Ethereum mainnet you will need Ether to pay the transaction fees.

You can develop on a local testnet (e.g. ganache-cli) and/or public testnets:
Ropsten, Rinkeby, Kovan, Goerli.
For public testnets there are faucets which will give you testnet Ether to use.
There are also mobile wallets that will connect to public testnets.

For learning and development, a public testnet may meet your needs.